# RegEx for parsing IUPAC chemical formulas

Tags: regex

I need to match chemical formulas written in IUPAC form inside of texts. Here there is a example:

Discovery of **N-(5-Fluoropyridin-2-yl)-6-methyl-4-(pyrimidin-5-yloxy)picolinamide** (VU0424238): A Novel Negative Allosteric Modulator of Metabotropic Glutamate Receptor Subtype 5 Selected for Clinical Evaluation.

The own formulas are always in this style:

2-Chloro-4-[1-(4-fluoro-3-methyl-phenyl)-2-methyl-1H-imidazol-4-ylethynyl]-pyridine

2-chloro-4-[2-[1-(4-fluoro-3-methylphenyl)-2,5-dimethylimidazol-4-yl]ethynyl]pyridine

2-chloro-4-[2-[1-(4-fluoro-3-methylphenyl)-2-methylimidazol-4-yl]ethynyl]pyridine

2-chloro-4-[2-[1-(3-fluoro-4-methylphenyl)-2-methylimidazol-4-yl]ethynyl]pyridine

N-[[1-(4-chlorophenyl)-2-[2-(4-fluorophenyl)ethyl]imidazol-4-yl]methyl]-N-methylpyridin-4-amine

4-[2-[1-(5-chloropyridin-2-yl)-2-methylimidazol-4-yl]ethynyl]-2-methylpyridine

Is there a regular expression to find this kind of formulas?

Thanks,
A. Helle

Comment: Any idea about this regular expression?

Answer (score 0):

> The own formulas are always in this style

If so, this one could do the trick

```
([A-z]|\d)-[A-z\d\(\)[\]\-,]+
```